# Eigenfrequency of a beam?

Tags: classical-mechanics, solid-mechanics

How would you calculate the eigenfrequency of such a cantilever?

[image]

[image]

This is what I found so far, but I don't know how to apply it to this specific geometry: http://iitg.vlab.co.in/?sub=62&brch=175&sim=1080&cnt=1

Comment: "The" eigenfrequency?!

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano okay, to be correct, it would be the "eigenfrequencies"